# simdjson c++ - function arguments from known-length arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, json, parsing

I'm using the simdjson library to parse two lists of lists within a json object. The json data are provided by a third party, so I cannot modify the data structure.

The code looks like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "simdjson.h"

using namespace simdjson;

class Game{
    public:
    void update_a(float a, float b){
        std::cout << "A: " << a << " - " << b << std::endl;
    };
    void update_b(float a, float b){
        std::cout << "B: " << a << " - " << b << std::endl;
    };
};

int main(void)
{
    Game game = Game();
    ondemand::parser parser;
    auto json = R"( {
      "data": {
        "player_a": [
            ["x", 0.4, 1.999],
            ["y", 0.99, 1.24],
            ["x", 0.2, 1.45],
            ["z", 0.41, 1.1],
        ],
        "player_b": [
            ["w", 1.34, 1.3],
            ["q", 1.34, 1.3],
            ["x", 1.34, 1.3],
        ]
      }
    } )"_padded;
    auto doc = parser.iterate(json);

    ondemand::object data;
    ondemand::array player_a;
    ondemand::array player_b;

    auto error = doc["data"].get(data);
    if (error) { return 1; }

    error = data["player_a"].get_array().get(player_a);
    if (error) {
        std::cout << "Player A error: " << error << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for (auto move: player_a)
    {
        double up;
        double right;
        move.at(1).get(up);
        move.at(2).get(right);
        game.update_a(up, right);
    }

    error = data["player_b"].get_array().get(player_b);
    if (error) {
        std::cout << "Player B error: " << error << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for (auto move: player_b)
    {   
        std::cout << move << std::endl;
        double up;
        double right;
        move.at(1).get(up);
        move.at(2).get(right);
        game.update_b(up, right);
    }
}
```

Basically, I don't know *a priori* the lenght of the `player_a` and `player_b` arrays, but I know that each element in those arrays are fixed lenght arrays (three elements) and I have to call a function that takes as arguments the second and the third elements of such arrays.

The code above generate the following output, which is wrong:

```
A: 0.4 - 0
A: 0.99 - 0
A: 0.2 - 0
A: 0.41 - 0
A: 0.41 - 0
A: 0.41 - 0
A: 0.41 - 0
Player B error: Objects and arrays can only be iterated when they are first encountered.
```

Is maybe the `.at(1)` method used wrongly?

How could a correct and performant code look like?

Answer (score 2):

Yup, there's a *very* important caveat in the documentation of `at()`:
https://simdjson.org/api/1.0.0/classsimdjson_1_1_s_i_m_d_j_s_o_n___i_m_p_l_e_m_e_n_t_a_t_i_o_n_1_1ondemand_1_1array.html#a64b2a92de916b963eb298be7b2340f7c

> This function should only be called once as the array iterator is not reset between each call.

So, yeah, you're using `at(2)` wrong, but it's not your fault. Naming the method `at()` would give anyone a real expectation that it will work exactly like `at()` on an `std::vector`. Given the library's narrow focus on speed, I wouldn't be surprised if `at(N)` is just skipping N commas.

Anyway, you have to reset the iterator before using `at` again. Unfortunately, the reset method isn't available on the base `ondemand::value`. So you have to cast `move` to an `ondemand::array`

```cpp
for (auto move: player_a)
{
    ondemand::array move_array;
    error = move.get_array().get(move_array);
    if (error) {
        std::cout << "move error: " << error << std::endl;
        return 1;    
    }

    double up;
    double right;
    move_array.at(1).get(up);
    move_array.reset();
    move_array.at(2).get(right);
    game.update_a(up, right);
}
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to backtrack, you could manually step through an iterator:

```cpp
for (auto move: player_a)
{
    auto it = move.begin();
    ++it; // skip name

    double up;
    (*it).get(up);
    ++it;

    double right;
    (*it).get(right);
    game.update_a(up, right);
}
```

While testing this, I learned that the extra comma at the end of the JSON array causes it to do another iteration, and report a type error during `move.get_array().get(...)`. So, make sure the JSON is well formed because the error message is confusing!

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact I should have to reset the iterator after using `at( )`.
In terms of performance, I think the second approach is slightly more efficient, is that right?

Comment: It seems like a safe assumption - reset likely backtracks the parser back to the start of the array, and re-parses, while iterating the array will only do one pass. But it practice, with only 3 elements in the array, it might be such a small difference that it doesn't matter. I would just go with whatever approach you're more comfortable with.